# Changing each records int column value by 1 throws a duplicate error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

My entity has a column `Order` which value must be unique. I want to create a function that increments each record's `Order` by 1:

```
MyEntities db = new MyEntities();

var entities = db.Entity.Where(e => e.Order > 10);
foreach (var entity in entities)
{
    entity.Order++;
}
db.SaveChanges();
```

The problem is when saving changes. I get an error that there is a duplicate on column `Order`. I suspect it saves changes row by row and when it saves the first `Order`'s change the next wasn't processed yet and has the same value. Am I right? How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: You need to have context associated with the entity right ? only then db.SaveChanges() can track ??

Comment: Yes I have a context to a model generated from database.

Comment: Could you please paste that code where it it has the context association with it ?

Comment: Just added, `MyEntities` were auto generated using database first approach.

Comment: You have to start a end of list and move backwards : for (int i =  entities.Count() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    entity[i].Order = i;
}

Comment: @jdweng just tried it, same error. Just changed last line to `entity[i].Order++`

Comment: NO!!!!  What you did is wrong.  If you have two Order number that are now zero you will get both going to one.

Comment: Why? I don't want to assign reverse count to Order?

Comment: its entities[i].Order right ? not entity[i].Order. Secondly regarding the comment I dont understand because if you assign i to Order instead Order++ then there will be an issue with duplicate order number. and also try adding this db.Entry(entities[i]).State = EntityState.Modified;

Comment: Try reverse count as suggested by @jdweng with your entity[i].Order++ code but add a db.SaveChanges(); each time.

Comment: @JonRoberts - I thought the same but then i feel its bit inefficient to have that many commits when order count is big ?

Comment: @rootkonda possibly but we don't know dataset size.  Alternatively set them all to something unique first (like entity[i].Order + 1001), then save changes then loop again to subtract 1000. More computing, fewer commits.  Dodgy if it crashes mid update though!

Comment: I could only make it work with calling db.SaveChanges(); in every iteration. I'd rather to call it after all values are assigned. @JonRoberts EntitiyState.Modified didn't work.

Comment: @Pomme EntityState.Modified wasn't my suggestion.  I have given an alternative solution as an answer below. Whether that is preferable to issuing multiple SaveChanges is for you to decide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If not of the suggestions in comments work for you, you could code it at SQL directly like this:

```
        string Cmd = "UPDATE Entity SET [Order] = [Order] + 1 WHERE [Order] > 10 ";
        db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(Cmd);
```

Or if you want to use EF to select the dataset and construct the SQL Command from that, try something like:

```
            var entities = db.Entity.Where(e => e.Order > 10);
            string Cmd = string.Format("UPDATE Entity SET [Order] = [Order] + 1 WHERE [Order] in ({0})",string.Join(",", entities.Select(e => e.Order.ToString()).ToList()));
            db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(Cmd);
```

Comment: The problem is having a duplicate column when updating. When applying Save Changes after each update, it works (see comments). OP didn't want to issue savechanges after every iteration (see comments) and so a single SQL update would achieve the same thing.  It's a valid solution to this question. Please remove your downvote.

Comment: If you haven't fully understood the question, how can you downvote an answer? He is incrementing a set of Order IDs. So ID 10 becomes 11 but should not create a duplicate as ID 11 becomes 12.  However when he updates all ID ans then calls SaveChanges, the first update changes ID 10 to 11 before 11 has updated to 12.  Hence the error and why issuing Save Changes each time works.  The OP did not want to issue an update repeatedly within a loop, so this is a valid alternative.

Comment: I think I'll use it this approach I've never created sql commands in the application. Is it better to create stored procedures and call them or is there no difference? On minor thing `Order` needs to be in square brackets because this name is unique for sql.

Comment: @Pomme I'm not aware of any performance difference. Yes, good point, as Order is an SQL Keyword you'd need the square brackets.